# Bootstrap multiselect cloning issue

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-multiselect

I have a multiselect on one of my selects and it works fine when setup as detailed here, http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/.

I clone a div using the jquery clone method which contains this multiselect.

```
  $("select[id^=Test]").multiselect();
```

After cloning, the cloned select references the original select. I also change the ids of the cloned select to that is not the issue.
I have tried the multiselect methods such as rebuild but it still doesn't work. I created a fiddle to show the issue.
https://jsfiddle.net/zaa35zgt/3

Comment: When you click the "Clone" button, what should happen?  Should the last multiselect be cloned?

Comment: Yes, the div which contains the multiselect should be cloned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap multiselect alters the HTML of the containing div. It's not really a good idea to clone it the way you do since you will be cloning all the data and events as well. Instead you could clone the original select and then apply multiselect to it.

Something like this (modified the fiddle slightly):

```
$("select[id^=Test]").multiselect();

$($('[id*="btnClone"]')).on("click", function() {

     var clonedSelect = $('div[id^="clonedDiv"]').last().find('select').clone();

     var newDiv = $('<div></div>').append(clonedSelect);

     $('div[id^="clonedDiv"]').last().after(newDiv);

     newDiv.find('select').multiselect();

});
```

Comment: In the fiddle I only have 1 div with the select to clone but in reality I have other html to clone which contains this select. So maybe I should remove this select and re-append it.

Comment: I would suggest cloning everything but removing the elements that are multiselect specific. Then you recreate a new multiselect on the cloned select, making sure to remove any events and data attached to it.

Comment: I used Robban's suggestion and removed the button div in the cloned select that gets created by multiselect and then used the multiselect methods, destroy and rebuild to rebuild the multiselect. I updated the fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/zaa35zgt/5/